# Raspberry Pi speakers identification

Tags: audio, speakers

A less technical Pi-related question.

Can anyone identify what model of speakers have been used in the *Have It Your Way* [Raspberry Pi for home](https://www.raspberrypi.com/for-home/) marketing site?

I assumed they might be an official accessory and/or available on a Pi related store but haven't been able to find them anywhere.

[Speaker image](https://assets.raspberrypi.com/static/e8069c7de77233a10cec46ee134dd733/2b8d7/have-it-your-way.webp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used google lens to search for that image, found:

https://amzn.eu/d/dSOBOYV